# how to increase and decrease value(number of qty.)with ImageView?

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to Increase and decrease value of qty on clicked.
 i Used `ImageView`  for decrease and Increase the value in middle i used TextView for showing the value.

this thing is completely work in the Activity but i want perform this operation in ListView.

Here the complete code and it is working on simple Activity.

**qty.java**

```
public class qty extends AppCompatActivity {
    int minteger = 0;
    ImageView decrease;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.raw_order);
        decrease=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.decrease);
        decrease.setEnabled(false);


    }

    public void increaseInteger(View view) {
        minteger = minteger + 1;
        display(minteger);

    }public void decreaseInteger(View view) {
        minteger = minteger - 1;
        display(minteger);
    }

    private void display(int number) {
        TextView displayInteger = (TextView) findViewById(
                R.id.integer_number);

        displayInteger.setText("" + number);
    }
}
```

**raw_order.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/decrease"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/minus"
                android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:onClick="decreaseInteger"
                />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/integer_number"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/increase"
                    android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:onClick="increaseInteger"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/plus"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>
                </LinearLayout>
```

And i want to perform this same thing in ListView

**ListViewadapterorder.java**

```
     package omcommunication.orderdesign;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import static android.media.CamcorderProfile.get;

public class ListViewAdapterorder extends BaseAdapter  implements ListAdapter{
    Context cntx;
    SparseIntarray sia; // class variable
   // SessionManager session;
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder;
    View view;
    int minteger = 0;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private boolean status;
    public static final String KEY_EMP_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_ID = "o_id";

    ArrayList<String> o_aid = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> o_aproduct = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> o_aqty = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> o_atotal = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ListViewAdapterorder(Context context,
                                ArrayList<String> o_id,
                                ArrayList<String> o_product,
                                ArrayList<String> o_qty,
                                ArrayList<String> o_total
    ) {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        cntx = context;

        o_aid = o_id;
        o_aproduct = o_product;
        o_aqty = o_qty;
        o_atotal = o_total;

        alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do You Want To Call....");
     /*   session = new SessionManager(context);
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        uid = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);
*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return o_aid.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return o_aid.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            TextView mname , pmethod2, pamount3, premark4;
            final ImageView increase,decrease;
            final TextView displayInteger;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) cntx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(cntx);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_order, parent,
                    false);
            decrease = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.decrease);
            increase= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.increase);
            mname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mname);
            mname.setText("  " + o_aproduct.get(position));
            sia = new SparseIntarray(data.size());

             displayInteger = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.integer_number);

            increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int count = sia.get(position);
                    count++;
                    resultp.put(cout);
                    displayInteger.setText("" + count);
                }
            });


            return convertView;
        }

    private class SparseIntarray {
        public SparseIntarray(int size) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why ain't you using a `recyclerView` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **SparseIntArray** to store the value count for each position

in the listAdapter class define an instance variable

```
 SparseIntArray sia; // class variable
```

.. inside listAdapter constructor

```
sia = new SparseIntArray(data.size());
```

then in OnClick event

```
public void onItemClick(...) {

     int count = sia.get(position)

     // now increment or decrement as per your requirement
    // coutn++; or count--;   and save it

    sia.put(position, count);
```

**Edit 1:**

set OnClick listeners to your increase decrease imageViews in the getView() method,

```
 final displayInteger = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.integer_number);

increase.setOnClikcListener(new OnClickListener {   
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
   int count = sia.get(position);
   count++;
   sia.put(position, count);
   displayInteger.setText("" + count);
```

});

you can do the same with your decrease view

Comment: post the error! and the ListViewadapterorder constructor code

Comment: and getting error in sia.get(position) and  in sia.put(position, count); both get and put are in red font

Comment: ok so there was a typo in my code which I have corrected. It is actually SparseIntArray and not SparseIntarray, so you dont have to create the inner class, but import android.util.SparseIntArray. By looking at your code it seems you have already done it.

Comment: one more thing you are initialising sia at the wrong place, initialise it in the constructor. sia = new SparseIntarray(data.size()) this line should be after the line cntx = context. And with ListAdater I meant the adapter class which you have implemented. So if you are extending the BaseAdapetr you do not have to implement ListAdaper.

Comment: it is giving me error of null pointer exception in this line sia = new SparseIntarray(data.size())

Comment: it is solved... thanq... i just removed data.size from this line sia = new SparseIntArray(data.size()); and its work

Comment: the another problem i'm facing is that  when I move down to the page then it will directly show 0 and when I increase then it will give me the last qty.

Comment: Can you please help me in this too?

Comment: update your code so that I can see the changes and help. Meanwhile, in your getView() method, jus after initialisation of displayInteger textView try displayInteger.setText("" + sia.get(position)) // this will update your count according to the position while constructing the view

Answer (score 0):

Make an OnLickListener for the image view and call the methods,
For the list view you need to make an OnItemSelectedListener Or OnItemClickListener

Answer (score 0):

First You Need To Give The ImageView an ID; Then Do It Like This 
   In On Create :::

```
ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
img.setOnClickListener(imgclick);
```

Then In The Class Body ::::

```
OnClickListener imgclick=new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
           //Call The Methods Like Increase Number Or Decrease
    }
};
```

Comment: it is working on Simple Activity not in the ListViewAdapter or in ListView's Data..